# I can't launch an application with AVD (No Launcher activity found!)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device, launch

So, I've been searching for 2 hours, and I still don't find an answer to my problem.

I run my android project (Eclipse Luna) with the AVD, the emulator works but here are the logs:

**Android Launch!**

adb is running normally.

**No Launcher activity found!**

**The launch will only sync the application package on the device!**

Performing sync

Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'test1' is not available. Launching new emulator.

Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'test1'

New emulator found: emulator-5554

Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'

Uploading FindThem.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'

**Installing FindThem.apk...**

**Success!**

**\FindThem\bin\FindThem.apk installed on device**

Done!

I know it may be a problem in the AndroidManifest, but i've checked, and the code is ok:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity 
        android:name="com.app.findthem.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>                
            <category android:name="android.intent.action.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

(and it's followed by the others activity's).

I don't get it, can someone help me please? Sorry for my english, i'm french native. And sorry if the answer is already post somewhere, but I searched and found nothing that solve my issue.

Thanks for reading and helping.

Comment: post your code activity.  is it this `com.app.findthem.MainActivity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<category android:name="android.intent.action.LAUNCHER"/>
```

should be

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```